# How to write HQL Query with where clause

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want to retrieve value from db ,based on jsp textbox value please suggest me accurate HQL query for this purpose:

select all from table where name = en and password = pwd

I have tried for above work via this way but got error in

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("from User where Employee_Name= ?"+ a);
```

Error -:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: Do you have such field Employee_Name in User.java ? Use the equivalent java field not the DB field

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from User where Employee_Name= :name");
query.setParameter("name", "asdf");
List list = query.list();
```

or you can do the same as on the first answer

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is with the prepaid statement, you must use

```
hibernatemplate.find(String queryString,Object value)
```

Look here for more [spec](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#find%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Hope this code will fix it.

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("from User where Employee_Name=?",a);
```

Comment: eroor showing -: The method setLong(String, String) is undefined for the type List

Comment: if `a` is a string you must give `setParameter`

Comment: again same -:  The method setParameter(String, String) is undefined for the type List

Comment: its you have a `+` symbol insted of a ','.. ?? Is that the problem.?

Comment: setParameter is used with session factory, i haven't used that with `hibernateTemplate.find`. !! tell me the results after changing to
`getHibernateTemplate().find("from User where Employee_Name= ?", a);`

Comment: adjactly , here we are using spring injetion and hibernatetemplate feature, so our style needs changes.

Comment: did you changed the `+` to `,` symbol..??

Comment: infact i have not used + : query -: getHibernateTemplate().find("from User where Employee_Name= :name").setParameter("name",a);

Answer (score 0):

```
 Query query=session.createQuery("from User where Employee_Name= "+"'en'"+ 
 "and Employee_Pass= " + "'pwd'");

    List<User> list=query.list(); 

    Iterator<User > itr=list.iterator();  
    while(itr.hasNext()){  
        User q=itr.next();
```

> use getter method of User class to fetch all the values

```
    }
```